# Unable to send cookie while sending form data service in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, multipartform-data

below are the screenshots of the script

[raiseInquiry service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwh6s.png)

when i run i get error 401 unauthorized response from raise Inquiry service 
but login service is success but not able to add cookie with the login request even though i had added cookie manager.

and how can I add a file to the parameters(encircled in dark)in jmeter below screen shots
[screenShotPostman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Yfl.png)

When i ran the above scenario in postman it worked, and found out that no cookie is associated with the raise inquiry service

Answer (score 0):

Change the following configuration in `jmeter.properties` in `JMeter /bin` folder and try: (`remove # to uncomment`)

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true 
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Restart JMeter and run the script again.